# how to send list from controller to thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I need to send the data which is present in a list from my spring controller to thymeleaf (html) how can I send the data? after receiving how can I iterate the data in thymeleaf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your list inside your `ModelMap` or `ModelAndView` object then traverse it using `th:each` within your thymeleaf page.

From Java side:

```
modelMap.addAttribute("list", myListOfThings);
```

From Thymeleaf side:

```
<ul>
    <li th:each="item : ${list}">
        <span th:text="${item}">Default</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```