# thymeleaf iteration on a list

Tags: list, jsp, thymeleaf

I'm struggling with looping on a list using thymeleaf.
I've these two classes :

```
public class Contact {
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    private String email;
    private String phone;

public class ContactForm {  
    private List<Contact> contacts;
```

The following controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/get", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView get() {

    ContactForm contactForm = new ContactForm();
    contactForm.setContacts(Application.contacts);

    return new ModelAndView("add_contact" , "contactForm", contactForm);
}
```

And the view :

```
<form method="post" action="save.html" th:action="@{/save}"
    th:object="${contactForm}" modelattribute="contactForm">
    <table>
        <c:out value="${contactForm.contacts.size()}" />
        <tr th:each="contact : ${contactForm.contacts}">
            <td><input type="text" name="field1"
                th:field="${contact.firstname}" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="field2"
                th:field="${contact.lastname}" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="field3 "
                th:field="${contact.email}" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="field4"
                th:field="${contact.phone}" /></td>
        </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>
    <br>
    <input value="Save" type="submit">
</form>
```

The Application.contact is a List of Contacts with 4 elements inside.
The result on the browser for the line

```
<c:out value="${contactForm.contacts.size()}" />
```

is a "4" printed on the page so the object and the 4 elements are successfully passed to the view.
Unfortunately it never goes into the th:each and so nothing is printed inside.
What am I doing wrong here ?

Thanks for your time

Comment: In this code snippet <tbody> is missing while there is a </tbody>, how about in your real code?

Comment: In the real code there is actually a thead with the headers and a tbody, i've just deleted it for a shorter code, and meh, I forgot to delete the closing tbody...

Comment: I even tried to use a sample code found here
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20535600/how-to-send-list-from-controller-to-thymeleaf)
I send a List<String> with two elements on the view, i can see that the list has 2 items on the view. But the th:each doesn't work. Do I need to include some headers or something?

Comment: The <c:out value="${contactForm.contacts.size()}" /> is not Thymeleaf but JSP with (Sp)EL. Then I think that Thymeleaf is correctly setup. Do you have the namespace th declared (xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org") or the appropriate JPS tag? Do you have Thymeleaf resolvers configured?

Comment: You're right, it's jsp, It was just to highlight that my List is correctly sent to the view. I do have the th namespace declared, however I don't know about the resolvers. It's the first time i use thymeleaf, it's a spring-boot project by the way.

Comment: Ok, I'm also using Spring Boot with Thymeleaf, but with HTML5. Any reason why you chose JSP? Spring Boot should automatically configure Thymeleaf if it's on the classpath. Check Spring Boot and the Thymeleaf pages for configuring those two.

Comment: I don't have specific reasons. But, tell me if I misunderstand something. My contacts form should print 4 <tr> with the specific <td> since I send 4 elements in the list, right ? On my browser i see this output `<tr th:each="contact : [org.rps.wok.Contact@6a9a841a, org.rps.wok.Contact@202fa4ec, org.rps.wok.Contact@61e42e70, org.rps.wok.Contact@11fffafc]">
<td>
<td>
<td>
<td>
</tr>` But there is only one <tr>, Means that the elements on the list are here, but the contact var doesn't seems to work.

Comment: You're right. Looks like Thymeleaf is not properly configured. If you're using Maven, do you have 'spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf' dependency?

Comment: I didn't have, I added a thymeleaf dependency but not the spring-thymeleaf dependency. Since I've an error of finding template location at runtime, _Cannot find template location: classpath:/templates/ (please add some templates or check your Thymeleaf configuration)_ I think it wasn't really active.

Comment: That was the problem, I added the specific thymeleaf dependency for spring-boot, a template and I can retrieve my contact within my <table> Thank you for your help !

Comment: You're welcome, I put it as an answer. Could you mark it please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like Thymeleaf is not properly configured.

With Spring Boot and Thymeleaf you need at least the following dependecies in your pom to let Spring Boot automatically configure Thymeleaf:

```
<dependency> 
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
</dependency>
```